# Take x vector up to 8 full numbers and separate odds and evens and display in a rising order in c

Tags: c

I'm having issues trying to create a program in C that reads a vector with 8 full numbers and then proceeds to separate the odds and evens and displays them in a rising order.

What I've managed so far is to make the program display the numbers in a rising order but I can't separe odds and evens yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    int x[8];
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite um numero:");
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<8; i++)
        for (j=i+1;j<8;j++)
        {
            if (x[i]>x[j])
            {
                temp=x[i];
                x[i]=x[j];
                x[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    printf("Vetor em ordem crescente: \n");
    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf(" %d",x[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For even numbers just add this condition for the `printf` call: `if ((x[i] % 2) == 0) printf(" %d", x[i]);`. For odd numbers change `==` to `!=`. With that knowledge you should be able to add a loop to print the even numbers and then another loop for the odd numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check whether the number is odd or even when printing it:

```
printf("Even numbers:\n");
for(int idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++)
    if (idx  % 2 == 0)
        printf("%d ", x[idx]);
printf("\nOdd numbers:\n");
for(int idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++)
    if (idx  % 2 != 0)
        printf("%d ", x[idx]);
printf("\n");
```